# ffmpeg: concat Results in "Buffer queue overflow" and Short Audio

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I have this video file that at one point introduces an async of ~1 second. So I tried to make it work by duplicating a short segment at that point as it's silent there:

```
$ ffmpeg -i DFW.mp4.mkv -filter_complex '
[0:a] aselect=n=3:e=lt(t\,18*60+42.100)+gt(t\,18*60+41)*2 [as] [ae] [am];
[am] asplit [am1] [am2];
[as]  asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [as];
[am1] asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [am1];
[am2] asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [am2];
[ae]  asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS [ae];
[as] [am1] [am2] [ae] concat=n=4:a=1:v=0 [a]' -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy DFW-1.mp4
```

In other words I have

- `as` the start until 18:41.000
- `ae` the end from 18:42.100
- `am` the middle section between 18:41.000 and 18:42.100, which should be repeated once

The segmentation works, the concatenated audible part sounds good. However, `ae` turns out to only be ~5 seconds short and `ffmpeg` starts to print spammy "Buffer queue overflow, dropping"-lines. The entire video is 1h30 long leaving me with plenty of silence until the end.

In other words the video and audio are fine until about 18:48.000 and the remaining 1h11 of the video has no audio.

Why is `ffmpeg` doing that and how can I fix it?

*I also tried to include a silence audio segment instead as plan B, but failed.*

Comment: A buffer overflow occurs when a filter having multiple inputs is waiting on one or more inputs, which are late. The inputs already queued have a frame drop threshold which is crossed if those inputs are sufficiently late. What's wrong with just adding a blank segment?

Comment: @Mulvya Well, I failed creating/using one. It would solve my problem, though. -- But, then again I don't know why ffmpeg stops after five seconds. I'd say either use the entire rest of the stream or nothing at all. However, `ae` is ~5 seconds long, which is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no timestamp discontinuities in the audio, a simple atrim and a null segment should work.

```
ffmpeg -i DFW.mp4.mkv -filter_complex '
[0:a]asplit[a][b];
[a]atrim=0:1122.1[pre];
[b]atrim=1122.1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[post];
anullsrc,atrim=0:1.1[seg];
[pre][seg][post]concat=n=3:a=1:v=0[a]' -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy DFW-1.mp4
```

Comment: Ah, so this is how that's done. Cool.

Comment: After inserting five pauses like this ffmpeg starts to complain about "Buffer queue overflow, dropping" again

Comment: What's your new command?

Comment: I use the exact same way like you do. I just change the positions in the `atrim`s.

Comment: As in multiple commands? Or additional filters in single command?

Comment: Well, I took your call and executed it multiple times with different values for the `atrim`s.

Comment: Still not clear. Multiple or single command?

Comment: Again, exactly what you posted in your answer. Anyway, we were told that we will get a full audio stream from a different source and hopefully can apply that to the entire video.